# How to point a submodule in a project repo to a local submodule's repo directory outside the project repo?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule within a project repo, its path is ./project/dependency. And I have the dependency repo, and its path is ./dependency. How do I point the ./project/dependency to ./dependency so when I modify ./dependency, the changes can be seen by the project repo?

I tried the following commands but didn't work:

```
git submodule deinit -f ./project/dependency

Remove the submodule from the parent repository’s .gitmodules file by running the following command:
git rm --cached ./project/dependency

Add the new submodule by running the following command:
git submodule add <path_to_dependency> ./project/dependency

Update the submodule to the latest commit by running the following command:
git submodule update --init --recursive
```